# Извлечение индексов элементов массива из from.value, to.value

Tags: javascript, html, css

Столкнулся с вопросом - нужен скрипт на JS, который в заданном тексте удалит один или два символа, выбранных случайно с помощью мыши.

Подскажите как будет выглядеть событие выделения подстроки, длиной не более двух символов и событие удаления выбранных символов по щелчку мыши или нажатию кнопки Enter.

Я написал следующий код

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Delete Symbols</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>В тексте ниже выделяйте символы, щелкайтем или нажимайте Enter</p>
<p id='sometext'>Тестовый текст</p>
<script src="deletesymbols.js"></script>
</html>
```

Удаление происходит по событию `onclick`, но до этого необходимо проверить выделена ли подстрока, длиной не более двух символов. Каким образом осуществить эту проверку? Как получить индексы выделенных символов? Нашел описание классов `Selection\Range` на [Описание классов](https://learn.javascript.ru/selection-range), но непонятно как получить индексы выделенных символов тега `<p>` с помощью объектов `Selection\Range` (дело касается 1-го или 2-х операторов, судя по условию задачи)

P.S. Нашел код на этой же странице [Класс Selection](https://learn.javascript.ru/selection-range)

```html
<!doctype html>
<body>
<p id="p">Выдели меня: <i>курсив</i> и <b>жирный</b></p>

От <input id="from" disabled> – До <input id="to" disabled>
<script>
  document.onselectionchange = function() {
    let {anchorNode, anchorOffset, focusNode, focusOffset} = document.getSelection();

    from.value = `${anchorNode && anchorNode.data}:${anchorOffset}`;
    to.value = `${focusNode && focusNode.data}:${focusOffset}`;
  };
</script>
</body>
```

Как из `from.value` и `to.value` можно получить индексы выделяемых символов (начального и конечного)?

Comment: За что меня минусуют конкретно в данном вопросе?

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: подозреваю, потому что не привели код, который выполняет данную задачу в котором у вас какие-то сложности возникли

Comment: Приведите полный код, а не только HTML. HTML это не попытка решить задачу)

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, уберите минусы.

Answer (score 2):

Для начинающего разработчика

Давайте для начала разобьём задачу на независимые части, каждую из которых уже удобно делать

> Напиши скрипт на JS, который в заданном тексте удалит один или два
> символа, выбранных случайно

Во первых возникает вопрос - какой именно текст?

1. текст в поле ввода `<input />`
2. тест в контейнере `<div></div>`

В любом случае задача будет состоять из следующих этапов

1. получить текст из заданного объекта в переменную
2. определить какие именно символы будут удалены из строки
3. сформировать новую строку
4. занести сформированную строку в заданный объект

Идём дальше:

> Усложнение: удалять можно только буквы в
> словах, а знаки пунктуации и цифры удалять нельзя

по сравнению с предыдущей задачей придётся модифицировать этап 2) и делать проверку - является ли символ в строке по определённой позиции запрещённым и если да, то продолжить поиск символа для удаления

> Усложнение: принять,
> что этот текст является программной на Javascript, удалить одну-две
> команды JS, но только если они не в строковых литерах (break как
> команду удалить можно, а в строке "break my heart" нельзя)

Здесь потребуется принципиально другой алгоритм этапа 2)

> Усложнение:
> воспользуйся этим скриптом и "попорти" код какого-нибудь другого
> скрипта на Javascript, а потом отладь, найди ошибку и восстанови
> работоспособность

--

Вернемся к самой первой задаче. Как я понимаю, требуется использовать только чистый js, никакого jquery?

Этап 1) получить текст из заданного объекта в переменную

```
<p id='sometext'>Тестовый текст</p>
```

Для этого потребуется команда `querySelector`:

```
let element = document.querySelector('#sometext');
```

А для того, чтобы получить текст из элемента свойство `innerHTML`

```
let text = element.innerHTML;
```

Если же используется для ввода текст элемент `<input>`, тогда необходимо использовать свойство `value`

```
let text = element.value;
```

Этап 4) записать текст из переменной в заданный объект делается также:

```
element.innerHTML = text;
```

или

```
element.value = text;
```

Этап 2) определить какие именно символы будут удалены из строки

Для определения случайной позиции в строке (случайного натурального числа) потребуется функция

```
Math.random()
```

функция возвращает случайное значение от 0 до 1, поэтому чтобы получить позицию в строке требуется

1. узнать размер строки
2. умножить случайное число на размер строки
3. округлить вверх или вниз полученное значение

т.е.

```
const str_len = text.length;
const rnd = Math.random();
const index = Math.ceil(str_len * rnd);
```

`Math.ceil(x)` откидывает дробную часть числа

Остаётся этап 3) когда требуется собрать новую строку, в которую требуется включить все символы до найденной на этапе 2 позиции и все символы после найденной на этапе 2 позиции:

Для этого есть функция `substring(start, end)`, т.е.

первая часть строки будет

```
const part1 = text(0, index);
```

вторая часть строки будет

```
const part2 = text(index + 1, str_len);
```

или
const part2 = text(index + 1);
поскольку если не указывать конец подстроки, то подстрока будет выделена до конца строки

и осталось склеить 2 части, чтобы получить новую строку

```
const new_text = part1 + part2
```

Comment: а как быть если удаляемые символы выбираются не случайно, а с помощью мыши? Как получить индексы символов удаляемой подстроки с целью определения ее длины (не более 2)?

Comment: @junior developer, можно решить задачу в лоб - если требуется нажимать мышкой на символ и символ удаляется, то можно строку сформировать в виде набора букв, типа <div>П</div><div>р</div><div>и</div> и просто менять `css` свойство блоку в котором была буква и на которое нажал пользователь - делать `display: none`

Comment: @junior developer, вот эту фразу не понял `Как получить индексы символов удаляемой подстроки с целью определения ее длины (не более 2)?`

Comment: выделяются несколько символов. Если длина выбранной подстроки <=2, то происходит удаление выбранной подстроки.

Comment: ок, т.е. пользователь мышкой выделяет текст - так? тогда главный вопрос - где он выделяет текст - просто в элементе `div` или в поле `input` или `textaarea`?

Comment: в элементе `div`.

Comment: @junior developer, тогда нужно использовать это https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection